# Can we pass two parameters in $routeProvider.when() function in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider

I am trying to redirect **home.html** for two path(s),

for e.g I have a anchor tag like this
`<a href="/home">Home</a>` And it could be `<a href="/index">Home</a>`,
In both case I want it to redirect on single URL (**home.html**)

What I tried

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
        .when("/home", "/index", {
            templateUrl : "home.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo : "home"
        });
    });
```

But the my above code is not working. Is there any other possible solution for this? If so please suggest, thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend having two URLs that root to the same location. Rather use a redirect (`redirectTo `).

Comment: I just want a condition like It can be #one or #two , I am not saying redirect two thing at once

Comment: Yes, but the API of the router doesn't allow what you're trying to do :-(

Comment: That's the issue :( can we achieve it using vanilla JavaScript condition in angular?

Comment: Doubt it. But switching to the new component router or UI router, might help.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
        .when("/home", {
            templateUrl : "home.html"
        })
       .when("/index", {
            templateUrl : "home.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo : "home"
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the $routeProvider .when requires une string and an object as shown here in the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Anyway, you can use ui-router to build more complex routing:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: What is diffrenece between route provider and ui-router, Is that same?

Comment: ui-router is a independent module that adds extra functionalities to the angular router, have a peek in the link i provided ;)

Comment: Thanks! going to grab :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add two routes instead of merging them ..

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
        .when("/home", {
            templateUrl : "home.html"
        })
        .when("/index", {
            templateUrl : "home.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo : "/home"
        });
    });
```